# Как настроить codespace под разработку на C# (asp.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code, ide

Появилась необходимость в использовании облачного IDE. Как я понял, единственное нормальное решение - codespace от гитхаба. Создал на основе своего репозитория пространство, подгрузил все необходимые зависимости проекта и необходимые для VS расширения, но редактор обсыпал меня кучей ошибок (см фото)[image: Список ошибок]

Вручную скачал dotnet sdk 8.0, попробовал сбилдить и запустить - все работает, никаких ошибок/предупреждений не выдает. То есть я так понимаю, проблема именно в редакторе. Какие есть способы это исправить и починить codespace?

На фото все скачанные расширения

[image: Расширения]